# Recover sharepoint after uninstall project server

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a big, big problem.

After uninstall project server for sharepoint 2010, it doesnt start any page or the central admin page, looking here http://www.sharepointboris.net/2011/10/disaster-recovery-after-uninstalling-project-server-2010/ will got the solution but I can´t remember the passphrase, there is some way to recover it and finish the sharepoint restoration?

Thank for your in-time answer

Thanks for the answers, finally I find the passphrase writed somewere in a notebook, when the administration site assitant was run, I write the passphrase and everything was restore to the original state

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you don't have a backup, either. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I got a backup for share point

Answer (score 2):

If you can get to the management shell enter into the powershell prompt:

```
$passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
```

This will reset the passphrase.  You should note that it is not possible to retrieve a passphrase.

Comment: When I try that command, the server answer I don't have connection for share point farm

Comment: Can you possibly recover from your backup? I don't know the reasons why you decided to uninstall project server but if you can recover from your backup and get everything running you can then reset your passphrase and redo what you were trying to do.  Otherwise you need to reconnect the farm first.  This is an interesting article [here](http://mikessharepoint.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/forgot-farm-passphrase-to-the-only-sharepoint-server-recreate-farm-walkthrough/) that may help you reconnect your original farm

Comment: I install the project server for testing purposes (long history) but I didn't had the license so I had to uninstall it.

Comment: It wasnt necesary, I find the passphrase and with it I can restore the sharepoint connecting to Sharepoint_Config data base